# How to open multiple pages from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have a page that exports a PDF file via parameters that will be passed to it from query string. For example:

```
PrintPage.aspx?CustomerId=1
```

will export a PDF with information about the customer #1.

now I have an ImageButton in another page (Lets call it CallerPage.aspx) and I want to call PrintPage.aspx multiple times with multiple query string values like this:

```
foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
{
    HyperLink lnk = new HyperLink();
    lnk.NavigateUrl = "PrintPage.aspx?CustomerID=" + customer.ID;
    lnk.Target = "_blank";
}
```

But I don't know how to navigate the hyperlinks that I've created.

I've also tried Response.Redirect but it doesn't work as well

```
foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
{
    Response.Redirect("PrintPage.aspx?CustomerID=" + customer.ID, false);
}
```

It only redirects to the last page (and without the false parameter it will redirects to the first page)

So please help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: You cannot really do what you are trying... Could you just render the links on the page and let the users click them?

Comment: What an amazing question! Its not possible to do what you are trying to achieve. Period.

Comment: May be you can do this with a javscript function. But it is not possible to do at all with c#.

Comment: So sad. Can someone put some javascript code please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once sent to client you cannot open new URL from the code behind. You need javascript to do that. If you attache handler to onload page event you could open as many pages as you want. The other point is whether the client would like that ;-)

Comment: <body onload="test();"> <script>function test() { window.open('your_url_here','','width=200,height=100'); }</script> look also here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot. So how can I pass parameters to the javascript function (For example CustomerID in the question that I've asked) Can I call the javascript Function from code behind?

Comment: well I can think of few ways: 1st you could use location.search (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) or you could populate JavaScript variable using your code behind (var someVar = <%=this.MyInteger%>;) and last one you could create a hidden field (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) and set the value there.